# Event for change in text file content

Tags: java, file

My java program needs to know if a text file content changes. Currently Im using `File.lastModified()` method to do it but ideally I don't want to perform the check. Instead I want an event to fire every time the file is modified. Are there any third party libraries available for this kind of thing? I've heard it can be accomplished using `apache file descriptors` but couldn't find any information regarding it.

Comment: For the mentioned WatchService an explaining [tutorial](http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.de/2013/03/jdk7-explore-7-nio2-watch-service-api.html). Mind its API is still not a callback, but a polling loop, as you get a queue of watched files. But that can be wrapped. Important is its OS efficient watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Apache's [DefaultFileMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileMonitor.html).

All you need to do is add the file in question to the list of files that need to be monitored and start the monitoring thread.

If the file has been changed or deleted it shall fire an OnChange event.

Comment: Chose your answer over Will's because this lets me monitor a file directly whearas Java watch service monitors a directory and then I have to extract the file from event.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the new [Java 7 WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). This enables you to watch a directory and be notified of create, modified and delete events.

Answer (score 2):

*There are many factors that might determine your solution. How often the files updates, what type the information is, etc...*

My advice would be either the Java 7 standard, or the Apache de facto standard (if the requirement wont allow Java 7 solution)...

---

**Apache configuration**

> If it is a file that is kind of property information, a configuration, then you might want to look at Apache commons configuration. Which gives a refresh method each time the file is updated, to reload your configuration, etc. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_events.html#An_example

---

**Java 7, WatchService**

> If you use Java 7, look at the WatchService, link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

---

**Apache IO**

> If you dont want to use Java 7, and the file is not a configuration (which is better to use commons configuration that way), then you might want to look at FileAlterationObserver  from Apache io. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 0):

Google say that you can use libraries like [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) and [inotify-java](https://www.ohloh.net/p/inotify-java)